# Fail to read a value from a struture in C after assigning it

Tags: c

I have strange program behavior while trying to read a value from a structure after assigning a value to it. I'm showing the related structure and function below:

```
/*Data struct for cor_entry */
struct cor_entry {
    struct cor_entry * pre_entry;
    struct cor_entry * next_entry;
    long long unsigned int entry_data;
};
```

I've commented out most of my function to highlight the problem:

```
/* update correlation table */
void cor_table_update(long long unsigned int cor_table_data, 
    struct cor_entry **cor_table_head_ptr, 
    struct cor_entry **cor_table_tail_ptr, 
    int *entry_num, 
    const int MAX_NUM)
{
    struct cor_entry *cor_table_entry;
    int cor_hit=0;

    //test code 
    //cor_table_head=cor_table_tail=(struct cor_entry*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct cor_entry));
    //printf("original cor_entry_num=%d\n",*entry_num);

    ////////////////////////code for test///////////////////////////////

    cor_table_entry=(struct cor_entry*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct cor_entry));
    printf("The cor_table_entry=%x\n",cor_table_entry);
    cor_table_entry->entry_data=cor_table_data;
    if (cor_table_entry->entry_data==cor_table_data)
    { 
        printf("The assignment is correct!\n");
        printf("the cor_enrty_data=%x, stored data=%x,\n",
            cor_table_data,
            cor_table_entry->entry_data);
    }

    // ... rest of function
}
```

And I get this output while running the program:

```
The cor_table_entry=8c09a58
The assignment is correct!
the cor_enrty_data=8ffc8, stored data=0,
The cor_table_entry=8c09a70
The assignment is correct!
the cor_enrty_data=8ffc8, stored data=0,
The cor_table_entry=8c09a88
The assignment is correct!
the cor_enrty_data=8ffc8, stored data=0,
The cor_table_entry=8c09ae8
```

Could someone shed some light on this problem? I'm using the GCC-3.4.6 compiler.

Comment: what were you expecting?  ps. you might want to remove the redundant code

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem here... According to your output, the assignment is correct! Is `cor_table_data` not supposed to be 0, is that the problem?

Comment: @Martin @filipe If you don't bother reading the code, please don't comment. The problem is obvious and clear.

Comment: Sorry for the redundant code, I just want to avoid error while posting the problem.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - this is obviously homework, it might help them learn if the poster had done more than post block of code and said it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to compile with `-Wall`. GCC should then tell you that the sizes of the `%` format specifiers and the `printf()` arguments don't match. Try `%llx` instead of `%x`. That should fix the issue.

Comment: `%llx` because `entry_data` is `long long`

Comment: Hi, I have tried that, but the problem still here, besides the two printed value have the same type (long long unsigned int), and the same value(maybe), they should not display differently any way.

Comment: Please print `cor_table_data` was well.

Comment: I edited (just added a space) to be able to remove my downvote now that the format specifier is OK, as SO didn't let me dot it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with the printf, %x is not designed for showing long long unsigned. Split the value before printing it and it shall be what you expect.

You could also use `%llx` format specifier if your compiler support it.

Comment: Will downvoter explain what does not please him in my answer ? I know of format specifiers, but splitting values before printing also works! And the upvoted answer does not (yet) as it uses the wrong format specifier...

Comment: I'm beginning to be upset by those people who believe there is only one (right) way to do things. That is not programming, that is religion (and the worse aspects of it).

Comment: Inflexibility is not the domain of religion alone. :)